# Shell command to replace a string with & character

Tags: shell

I have a large text file which has a string "level 3". The occurrence of this string is multiple times so I dont want to replace it manually.

When I try the command:-

```
%s /level 3/&/g
```

It replaces "level 3" with att.

Is there any way? Thanks

Comment: `echo level 3| sed "s|level 3|\&|g"` ?

Comment: sed -i "s/level 3/&/g" yourFile.txt >> outPutFile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape the space and &, and your command will work. Like this -

```
%s /level\ 3/\&/g
```